# Extracting packet loss data from ping result in python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, ping

I am trying to get **packetloss** data from ping statistics. So far, I have a whole chunk of ping statistics data. I only need packetloss data in order to do `if packetloss < 10%: do something` in my python code. Here's my code:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

hostname = "8.8.8.8"
process = subprocess.Popen(['ping','-c','5',hostname],
stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Data:

```
$ ping -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=59 time=7.250 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=19.661 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 60.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 7.250/13.456/19.661/6.205 ms
```

Try following:

```
packetloss = float([x for x in stdout.decode('utf-8').split('\n') if x.find('packet loss') != -1][0].split('%')[0].split(' ')[-1])
if loss < 10.0:
    print("Loss is %s percent" % packetloss)
```

Comment: It works like charm. May I know which topic should I read on to be able to do decode in the future? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Nice to hear that it worked for your use case. You probably should look at string operations (decode, split, find) and list comprehensions

Comment: Can I do the same to find average round-trip which in above case is 13.456 ?

Comment: Something like 
avg_time = float([x for x in stdout.decode('utf-8').split('\n') if x.startswith('round-trip')][0].split('=')[-1].split('/')[1])

should work